# Firebase hosting redirect everything except one file

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting

I put the app-ads.txt in the root of my firebase site.
I'm trying redirect to 'www.my-site.com' except 'app-ads.txt'.

Fore example:

www.myFirebase.web.app/index.html --> redirect to www.my-site.com

www.myFirebase.web.app/app-ads.txt --> does not redirect

Here's my firebase.json

```
  {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "http://www.my-site.com",
        "type": 301
      },
      {
        "source": "/**",
        "destination": "http://www.my-site.com",
        "type": 301
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can't replicate, but just try using `"**"` as the source if you intend to catch everything.